# SparkSession throw Could not find or load main class

Tags: scala

I am using below code

```
package ConHToLocal
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
     println("No Error")
  }
}
```

It printing "No Error" and working fine. If I am adding SparkSession in import section to connect HIVE as below:

```
package ConHToLocal
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
     println("No Error")
  }
}
```

I am receiving error that

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ConHToLocal.Test
```

Please suggest me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution to Question**

1. Definitely it is an importing jar file libraries problem.
2. Please use maven dependency for spark sql, Here I have given the latest version. Based on your project requirement please choose the appropriate **spark sql** version.

   ```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
   ```
3. Try to re-run as scala application from your IDE.